# Resource not found exception after deploying SpringBoot war on Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat7

I'm trying to setup a RESTful application using Spring Boot and I've used  [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/#scratch)  tutorial as base to create one:

I have an index.html which refers to other pages as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="/sjob.html">Submit job</a>
    <a href="/tjob.html">Track Job</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My POM.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-uploading-files</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

My SpringBootServletInitializer subclass is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And there isn't anything significant in my application.properties file.
The application works fine as a standalone project, but once I package this as a war file and deploy it to my Tomcat7 server, it renders the index.html perfectly, but trying to access the referred pages: sjob.html and tjob.html gives me a HTTP Status 404 error specifying that the file was not found.
I've referred the Spring Boot instructions documented  [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)  to create the war file.
The resources index.html, sjob.html and tjob.html are placed in the static directory .

I've tried directly accessing these html files via localhost:8080/sjob.html but that also gives me the same error. I'm intrigued as to why is Tomcat able to load the index.html but not the other html pages even though they are in the same folder? Can anyone help me in identifying the issue here?

Comment: Your links do not contain the webapp context-path.

Comment: my context root is /

Comment: Have you got a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass in your app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes I have. I've updated the details with my subclass code as well.

Comment: File case-sensitivity? Or the files are not packaged in your war (unzip it). In what folder are the html files stored in your project?